# Play sound on a touch event?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am using the following code to play a sound when user touches anywhere at the screen but whenever i test it no sound is played and also when i use the same code on a button it plays on the second click on the button not on the first click??

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];


CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(320,480,0,0),point));//CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 130), point))
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    if(!player){

        NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/try.wav"];
        NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
        NSError* err;

        //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

        if( err ){
            //bail!
            NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
        }
        else{
            //set our delegate and begin playback
            player.delegate = self;
            [player play];
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;   // <---
if(!player){
```

Local variables are *not* automatically initialized to 0. Usually the content is some non-zero garbage, so the following `if` condition will seldom satisfy.

Looking at your code it seems that the `player` will be reused. Local variables will be lost once leaving the function. Therefore, you should make it an instant variable (ivar) of the view, or make it a static variable.

```
static AVAudioPlayer *player;   // <---
if(!player){
```